# Problem solving: Calculating area

Tags: geometry

I am an English teacher who occasionally helps students with their math . . . some students presented this problem set which after 35 years removed from Math I can't remember how to do the work. Students must show their work how they solved the problem.[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9rl3.jpg) [Problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y9DD.jpg)[Problem 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZawDS.jpg)

1 is the background information, 2 and 3 are problems based on 1

Comment: As much as I appreciate your service to your students (I wish I had teachers like you), this question is off topic for this site. We usually expect questions where users provide some context/effort in solving the problem, or what kind of help the user needs. See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) page for more details. In the meanwhile, why don't your students ask the math teacher for some help?

Comment: Thanks, actually I'm in a different school . ..  so I can explain the English part but wanted to see if I could find a bit of help for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

While the question is off-topic, it doesn't stop me from being kind to someone who is being kind (:

So the equation from the first picture is $2w + l = 200$, which allows us to express $w$ in terms of $l$, i.e. $w = (200 - l) / 2 = 100 - l/2$.

---

In the second picture, it is required that the width is at least $30$ and that the length is at least twice the width. This translates to $w \geq 30$ and $l \geq 2w$.

If we plug in the formula for $w$, we get: $100 - l/2 \geq 30$ and $l \geq 200 - l$.

It is then easy to simplify the inequalities and get: $l \leq 140$ and $l\geq 100$. Hence the answer is D.

---

In the third picture, we want a square shape, which means $w = l$. Therefore from the formula $2w + l = 200$ we now deduce that $3w = 200$, or $w = \frac{200}{3}$ (feet). Since $1$ yard is $3$ feet, it translates to $w = \frac{200}{9}$ (yards).

Hence the area of the square is $w^2 = \frac{40000}{81}$ square yards, or $493.8$ after rounded. The answer is C.